# Occasional 503 errors after upgrade YII2 project running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii2

I have a YII2 project running in production on AWS (elastic beanstalk (php 7.1) + 2 EC2 intances, an Application Load Balancer (with AWS WAF installed) + RDS) that wasn't updated for a long time, but was working perfectly.  Because I want to upgrade to a newer PHP-version, I also had to upgrade my YII2 project.  I ran composer (see output below), and after a few changes to the code, everything worked again on my local machine.

I uploaded the project back to AWS, and "occasionally" I receive 503-errors.  The errors pop up on different places, for example in the code snipped below when I update something in the DB and the page is redirected. But it happens that the same code runs 10 or 20 times perfect, and the next time I receive the errror.  The update in the DB succeeds everytime, but occasionally I receive the 503 when the page is redirected.

I'm really clueless on this one.  Anybody an idea of what the problem could be? (php is still 7.1)

Many thanks!

Nick

```
Package operations: 27 installs, 34 updates, 2 removals
  - Removing bower-asset/typeahead.js (v0.11.1)
  - Removing bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (3.2.7)
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.5 => 2.0.9): Loading from cache
  - Removing bower-asset/jquery (2.2.3)
  - Installing bower-asset/jquery (3.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Removing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.3.5)
  - Installing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.8.0 => v4.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Removing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (v2.0.6)
  - Installing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (2.0.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/inputmask (3.3.11): Loading from cache
  - Updating cebe/markdown (1.1.1 => 1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.10 => 2.0.35): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.6 => 2.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.17): Loading from cache
  - Updating swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.5 => v6.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.0.6 => 2.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Removing bower-asset/jquery-ui (1.11.4)
  - Installing bower-asset/jquery-ui (1.12.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-jui (2.0.6 => 2.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.9.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
  - Updating setasign/fpdi (1.6.1 => v2.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating mpdf/mpdf (v6.1.3 => v8.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-mpdf (v1.0.1 => v1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Updating bizley/cookiemonster (1.0.1 => 1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base (v1.8.7 => v1.9.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing npm-asset/bootstrap (4.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4 (2.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-nav-x (v1.2.0 => v1.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker (v1.4.3 => v1.4.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-bootstrap4-dropdown (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-dialog (v1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Removing kartik-v/yii2-grid (v3.1.1)
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-grid (dev-master 7b7199c): Cloning 7b7199cd40 from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-widget-rangeinput (v1.0.1 => v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Removing kartik-v/bootstrap-tabs-x (v1.3.2)
  - Installing kartik-v/bootstrap-tabs-x (dev-master fb38942): Cloning fb3894222c from cache
  - Updating phpoffice/phpexcel (1.8.1 => 1.8.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating mikehaertl/php-tmpfile (1.1.0 => 1.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating codemix/yii2-excelexport (2.0.0 => 2.7.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating kartik-v/dependent-dropdown (v1.4.4 => v1.4.9): Loading from cache
  - Downgrading kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop (dev-master 6918ca6 => v1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-codeception (2.0.5 => 2.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing opis/closure (3.5.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.7 => 2.1.13): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.0.5 => 2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating fzaninotto/faker (v1.6.0 => v1.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-faker (2.0.3 => 2.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.42.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/extensions (v1.5.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing jaimeperez/twig-configurable-i18n (v1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing gettext/languages (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing gettext/gettext (v3.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing whitehat101/apr1-md5 (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing robrichards/xmlseclibs (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing simplesamlphp/saml2 (v3.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp (v1.15.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-date-range (v1.6.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing select2/select2 (4.0.13): Loading from cache
  - Removing kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform (dev-master 2807832)
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform (dev-master 4d578ff): Cloning 4d578ff550 from cache
  - Removing kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 (dev-master e135c25)
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 (dev-master d44105a): Cloning d44105a4cb from cache
```

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    URLCheck::checkBeschikbaarBudgetID($id);

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id'=>$model->id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using load balancer ? also add the full error , or go to your logs and see what the actual error is, you can view `runtime/logs/app.log` given that you are using basic-app

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thank you for your reply.  Yes, I'm using a load balancer (AWS application load balancer).  I don't see any errors in the app.logs.  I also tried to change the code to see what line is causing the problem, and it looks like the problem can be solved by changing the redirect into a runAction(controller/action, [id->$model->id]).  Still no idea what is causing this problem and not sure if I should update the "redirect" in all places where it is used.

Comment: NO i dont think you need to change the `redirect` method i thought that the reason the app.log does not have the errors can be because you are reaching the connection limit for the load balancer

Comment: It is possible that it has something to do with the load balancer, but it seems very unlikely that I'm reaching connection limits.  The AWS application load balancer can handle lots of requests and I'm even experience the problem on a test environment where I am the only user.  For now I did change the redirect method because that solves the problem.  I understand that this is only a workaround, but it works and I can't afford to many errors in the production environment.